# How to add 2 variable inputs to txt file save name with php

Tags: php, variables, save

I want to make the name & date enetered in text boxes as the save name for the .txt file the answers save to if that makes sense. Currently I can get it to use the name variable but not both?

Heres my code:

```
<?php
$answer1="";
$answer2="";
$answer3="";
$answer4="";
$answer5="";
$answer6="";
$answer7="";
$answer8="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //if button is clicked do this:
    $name = $_POST['myname'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $answer1 = $_POST['q1answer'];
    $answer2 = $_POST['q2answer'];
    $answer3 = $_POST['q3answer'];
    $answer4 = $_POST['q4answer'];
    $answer5 = $_POST['q5answer'];
    $answer6 = $_POST['q6answer'];
    $answer7 = $_POST['q7answer'];
    $answer8 = $_POST['q8answer'];
    $answersText = "QUESTION 1\r\n\r\n". $answer1. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 2\r\n\r\n". $answer2. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 3\r\n\r\n". $answer3. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 4\r\n\r\n". $answer4. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 5\r\n\r\n". $answer5. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 6\r\n\r\n". $answer6. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 7\r\n\r\n". $answer7. "\r\n\r\nQUESTION 8\r\n\r\n". $answer8. "\r\n\r\n";
    $file = fopen($name ".txt","w");
fwrite($file, $answersText);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $file = fopen($name ".txt","w");
```

to

```
 $file = fopen($name . $date . ".txt","w");
```

Comment: that great cheers, worked fine. Another quick one as I'm new to php, I cant get it to save to my folder "Answers" which is located in the directory where file.php is stored.

Comment: change fopen as fopen("Answers/" .$name.$date.".txt","w"); it may still not save, if Answers folder doesn't have permission, also, make sure if you are linux use lower case to ensure you didn't make mistake :).

Comment: thanks a lot guys helped me out, been trying all different methods and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

something like this I think you mean?

```
$file = fopen('Answers/'.$name."_".$date.".txt","w");
```

Be very careful saving files with filenames based on input from the web, it's input you cannot trust so be sure to thoroughly validate and clean the inputted data.